# tSNE with groups of different size - reduce dataset or set perplexity = largest group?

Tags: r, dimension

Plotting a proteome dataset with tSNE I encounter the problem that I have a large healthy group (70) and rather few samples per genotype group (3-8).
How should I set the perplexity in this case?
Or would it better to separate the healthy cases form the diseased ones (they are clearly separated in PCA, euclidean dist ect)?

Thanks a lot!
Sebastian

Side quest: would you use batch-corrected or rather uncorrected data for the visualisation? For PCA the corrected ones look much better but I wonder if using it in tSNE would be overfitting?

Comment: If pca looks good i wouldn't bother with t-sne. Btw this is more suited for crossvalidated.